# Is the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{1/(x+3)-1/3}{x}$ equal to $-\frac{1}{9}$?

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{1}{x+3}-\frac{1}{3}}{x}$$

Is the limit $-\displaystyle{\frac{1}{9}}$?

Comment: Yes. You are correct

Comment: Your picture shows $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\frac{1}{x+3}-\frac{1}{3}}{x}$, while you ask about `Lim [(1-x/3)-(1/3)]/x x-->0`, which is $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\left(1-\frac{x}{3}\right)-\frac{1}{3}}{x}$, which does not exist (as a two-sided limit). Please clarify.

Comment: Woah. My bad. It's the one in the picture. Just fixed it to match.

Comment: @HiDanny your "fix" just made it worse.  Someone had just properly typeset it for you.  When writing math, `1/x+3` is taken to mean $\frac{1}{x}+3$, not $\frac{1}{x+3}$.  If you want $\frac{1}{x+3}$ and you do not properly typeset using TeX or MathJax, then you must use parentheses for the denominator as `1/(x+3)`.

Answer (score 3):

First combine the numerator, it doesn't even need l'Hospital:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{3-x-3}{3x+9}}{x}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{-x}{3x+9}}{x}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{-1}{3x+9}}{1}$

And here is already clearly visible the result.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{1}{x+3}-\frac{1}{3}}{x}$$
Lets denote $f(t)=\frac{1}{t}$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(3+x)-f(3)}{x}$$
Now wait a second, it looks familiar
$$f'(3)\equiv \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(3+x)-f(3)}{x}$$
And we know that
$$f'(t)=\frac{-1}{t^2}$$
Thus
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{1}{x+3}-\frac{1}{3}}{x}=\frac{-1}{9}$$
This method should not be considered a "valid solution", since the derivative is defined by the limit, but it's a nice way look at it

Comment: Use \lim in math mode to produce $\lim$.    Also, $$f'(3) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(3 + h) - f(\color{red}{3})}{h}$$  Here, $h$ is $x$.

Comment: you're right, fixed it

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\dfrac1{x+3}-\dfrac13}x=-\frac1{3(x+3)}.$$ You should be able to conclude.